# Symplectic group over finite field and quaternions

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, quaternions

Symplectic group over finite field is defined as group preserving non-degenerate antisymmetric bilinear form on $\mathbb F_q^{2n}$. How could we define this group using quaternions ? This should be group of $n\times n$ matrices with quaternion entries preserving hermitian form.

I know that there might be troubles with definition of quaternions over finite field. One approach is to use Cayley-Dickson formula. Second is to use some 4-dimensional subalgebra of octonions.

$q=2$

Let us define quaternions $\mathbb H_2$ as algebra $M_2\mathbb F_2$. It is generated by two invertible $t,u$ with conjugation and relations $\bar t=1+t, \bar u =u, ut=\bar tu$. This algebra contains $6$ invertible elements (forming group $S_3$) and $9$ zero divisors. Conjugation for matrix $x$ having single $1$ on diagonal is expressed as $\bar x=1+x$ otherwise it fixes element.

In this case I claim that group of $n\times n$ quaternion matrices $\{A A^*=I\}$ form $S_{2n}(2)$ finite simple group. $A^*$ denote transposed conjugated matrix to $A$. I have verified this in GAP for $n=2,3$.

**Complex case**

Let $\mathbb C_1$ be subalgebra of $\mathbb H_2$ generated by zero divisor $a$ such that $aa=a$. In this case $\bar a=1+a$ is second zero divisor in algebra. Let us call this algebra *split complex numbers over field with two elements*. Subgroup of $\{A A^*=I\}$ with elements from $\mathbb C_1$ form $L_n(2)$ finite simple group.

Let $\mathbb C_2=\mathbb F_4$ be subalgebra of $\mathbb H_2$ generated by $t$. Let us call this algebra *complex numbers over field with two elements*. Subgroup of $\{A A^*=I\}$ with elements from $\mathbb C_2$ form $U_n(2)$ finite simple group.

$q=3$

For field with three elements define quaternions as $M_2\mathbb F_3$. Conjugation exchanging elements on main diagonal and change sign for off-diagonal elements. In this case $n\times n$ quaternion matrices $\{A A^*=I\}$ form group $Sp_{2n}(3)$. It is tested in GAP for dimensions 2 and 3.

**Geometry**

Let us define projective space over quaternions in following way:

$\mathbb HP_q^n=\frac{Sp_{2n+2}(q)}{Sp_{2n}(q)\times Sp_2(q)}$

The size is $20, 336, 5440$ for $n=1,2,3$ and $q=2$. General formula in case of $q=2$ is $2^{2n}\frac{2^{2n+2}-1}{3}$.

**Question**

Have anyone thought of defining symplectic or unitary group over finite field using algebra of complex or quaternion numbers as I tried to sketch above ?

Comment: Is not standard notation Sp (rather than S)?

Comment: I use notation from Atlas of finite group representations: http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/

Comment: Oh I see - good to know. Would prefer Sp anyway, but the Atlas is... the Atlas

Comment: Yes, in context of my question I prefer Sp as well in order to have connection to compact Sp(n). Another drawback of Atlas notation is doubled index for symplectic groups. In n-dimensional quaternion space we obtain $S_{2n}$ or $Sp_{2n}$.

Comment: I think you are wrong about the Atlas notation. In the Atlas, $S_4(3)$ denotes the simple group ${\rm PSp}_4(3) = {\rm Sp}_4(3)/Z({\rm Sp}_4(3))$. The Atlas uses ${\rm Sp}_4(3)$ or sometimes $2.S_4(3)$ to denote the symplectic group itself.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. It is similar as $SL$ and $L$ for linear groups which stands for $PSL$. Anyway my question and notation is OK. We can say that letter $P$ added for projective group eats sometimes first letter and sometimes the second...

Comment: I don't know whether this is relevant, but there is an embedding ${\rm Sp}_n(q) \to {\rm SU}_n(q)$ for even $n$ (where ${\rm SU}_n(q)$ is defined over the field of order $q^2$).

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  Can't one use quaternion algebras over any field to define symplectic groups (though perhaps something funny happens in characteristic 2)?  And over finite fields, you only have the split quaternion algebra, $M_2(F)$.

Comment: @Kimball During the lent season I tried to withdraw from MO. Answering your comments - I agree with your second and third sentence. However I cannot find such definition anywhere. When I look into the book about "finite simple groups" then I find definition as in the first sentence of my question. Probably such definition is easier than the one with "quaternions". Anyway for me "quaternions" and "complex numbers" over finite field looks more interesting.